# Enabling CORS in an API gateway

Tags: angularjs, http, cors

I am making a Cordova application. I need to make a simple GET request with Angular.

I keep getting the message:
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://myserver/AuthenticateMe. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

I thought I added all the necessary headers to my response. Here is the full header:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Content-Encoding: gzip

Content-Length: 76

Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Date: Mon, 16 Mar 2015 21:37:56 GMT

Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1"
```

I tried this in Firefox and Chrome.

This is extremely annoying because I never had a problem with my server when I was doing native iOS and Android requests.

Am I missing anything here???

Comment: Have you tried specifying the exact URI instead of the wildcard '*'?

Comment: I just gave that a try, it didn't work. 
Even if it did, the URI making the request won't always be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try jsonp?

Something like:

```
$http.jsonp(API_URL + "/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
.success(function(data) {
    // blah blah
})
.error(function() {
    console.log("couldn't fetch.");
})
.finally(function() {
    // blah blah
});
```

Comment: jsonp does indeed reach the server, but it will not work for me because it does not read http headers. I need to add an authorization header to this request, and jsonp simply ignores it.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing, but I think you also need to specify which HTTP verbs you want to allow for CORS.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
```

or

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
```

Comment: Just tried adding both of these, still having the same issue.

Comment: Ok, I read your comment above that you need to pass an authorization header? Can you add that to your Access-Control-Allow-Headers? i.e. `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization`

Comment: I gave it a try, same exact message. I think my problem has something to do with the preflight response that Angular wants. My gateway won't add the response headers until authorization is done, and authorization cannot be done until Angular gets the proper headers to allow CORS.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry I do not know. The only final thing I can point you to is [http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) which discusses preflight requests. It also mentions `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` and setting `xhr.withCredentials = true;` on the XmlHttpRequest object.